# Any way to integrate Microsoft Word with Google Docs?

Tags: microsoft-word, google-docs, integration

Is there anyway for me to edit word docs that I saved on Google Docs from Microsoft Word (e.g. read from Google Docs and save to Google Docs)?

Perhaps via some kind of bridge?  Maybe there is an app that treats Google Docs as a hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [OffiSync](http://offisync.com/)